# How to add final keyword to variables automatically during add controls to JFrame in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I want create a simple GUI application with Eclipse. I add a JButton into JFrame. I want whenever clicked on button, the text of button chenged to 'Hello'. I use following code:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnNewButton.setText("Hello");
        }
    });
```

but i get following error:

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable btnNewButton inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

[image]

I search in internet and find out that i must add **final** keyword to first of variable like following:

```
final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
```

this problem solved, but my question is how to add final keyword to variables automatically during add controls to JFrame in Eclipse?

Comment: The pop-up is already providing you an option to change the modifier.

Comment: how to add final keyword during add control to jframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse go to following menu :

```
Window -> preferences-> WindowsBuilder-> Swing -> Code Generation
```

in **Variable generation** section in **Local** section checke the **Declare variable as 'final'**

[image]